# Button Clicking Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, button

I am making a quiz app and on one of my questions (I won't tell you which one in case I upload this app ;)) but when I click on the answer, the simulator lags for a second and quits, which I assume simulates a crash on a iPhone. Here is the message it gives me:

```
2016-12-23 22:23:38.060 Quiz App[9064:278885] -[Quiz_App.ViewController Btn3:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffce6507860
2016-12-23 22:23:38.084 Quiz App[9064:278885] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Quiz_App.ViewController Btn3:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffce6507860'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109600d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010691321e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109670f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109586005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109585b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000106de48bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000106f6ac38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000106f6af51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000106f69e4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000106e52545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000106e53c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106e009ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001075ed72d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001075e6463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001095a5761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010958a98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109589e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109589884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b540a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000106de2c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  Quiz App                            0x000000010633040f main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a5b068d start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

If someone could help it would be appreciated. (BTW This is my first app so I don't know how much works).

Comment: it says unrecognized selector sent to instance. post the code you have that handles the button click. If your using storyboard you probably didn't connect your button properly with the view controller.

Comment: Did you rename the Btn3: IBAction ?

Comment: its most likely your outlet issue, Please check outlet of this button

Answer (score 0):

Xcode project Target go to the "Link Binary with Libraries" option and click +.

Add CoreFoundation framework

and import CoreFoundation in File